# how to use FutureBuilder with FutureOr

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable of `FutureOr<Duration?>`, I'm assuming that it can return either `Future<Duration?>` or `Duration?`, right?

how can I use it with the `FutureBuilder` like a normal future method, that will wait for the `Duration?` if it's future, if not, just use the `Duration?` value directly.

when I try the following:

```
FutureBuilder<Duration?>(
            future: durationFuture,
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            /* my widgets implementations */
            },
          ),
```

this throws this:

```
The argument type 'FutureOr<Duration?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Duration?>?'
```

how the `FutureOr` type is working and how do I implement a FutureBuider based on it ?

Comment: can you include more about `durationFuture`

Comment: actually it's coming from an external package, and I want to know how to implemenet FutureBuilder with it

Comment: cant tell until I find the return dataType, It would be easier if you include the package/details

Comment: I'm using the just_audio package,  when playing an audio, it have a future duration to get audio duration, and I want to use it with the FutureBuilder

Comment: Try below answer, if fails consider including minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FutureBuilder<Duration?>(
  future: Future.value(durationFuture),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    /* my widgets implementations */
  },
)
```